# Java program hangs in the starthandshake() statement

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, network-programming

I have a Java program that tries to initiate ssl handshake with remote hosts. The following piece of code is used successfully with list of remote hosts. But I am facing a problem with one host where the program hangs in the handshake step. It does not execute the exception statements nor report any error. I made sure that port 443 and https service are on the remote host. Apparently, the problem is related to the remote host. Can anybody explain? How can I workaround it so my program continue ?

The following piece of code is the concerned part:

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(); 
System.out.println("Creating a SSL Socket For "+hostName+" on port "+port); 
SSLSocket socket=null;

socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostName, port);
System.out.println("Socket created");

try {
     socket.startHandshake(); //handshake
    } catch (IOException e1) {
      System.out.println("Handshake error: "+e1.getMessage());
      socket.close(); }

System.out.println("Handshaking Complete");
```

Comment: It sounds like the remote host is the problem, not your java code

Comment: Can you browse to that host:443?

Comment: Using Firefox, I got this message when trying host:443: `The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.`

Comment: Well there you are. Something wrong at their end.

Comment: @EJP: How can I control such situation? I want my program to not stop. At least, I want it to show me an error.

Comment: Set a read timeout on the socket with `Socket.setSoTimeout()` before the first I/O or `startHandshake()` call: then you will get a SocketTimeoutException or possibly an `SSLHandshakeException`.

Comment: In my experience startHandshake() hangs until the first byte is sent by the server.